# Matching last line from string \n\\\\\n[^] ] b

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string

```
\n\\\\\n[^] ] b
```

(litteraly)

`\\
[^] ] b`

I would like to match last line of this string.

I tried use this regexp `\n.*$` and it is not working. If I use `\\\\n.*$` it will work but I need to find some universal solution because if I have a string like `\nX\n[^] ] b` it will not work.

Thank you for advice.

**EDIT**:
I'm trying to match this pattern in sed pattern space. So I don't know if it act same as normal regex newLine character.
It looks like:

```
PATT:\n\\\\\n[^] ] b$
s/\n.*$//
```

Comment: [Your regex also works with `\nX\n[^] ] b`](https://regex101.com/r/mW0iS8/1). I think the problem is either with the approach, or the initial `\n`. Please provide the language and code you are using.

Comment: If you have `\\n` inside your strings and you want to match `\n` literal strings, I think you need this regex: [`(?<=\\n)(?!.*\\n).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/eA1lD2/2). Anyway, it is still not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[^\n]*$
```

You can get the last line by simply using this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/27

Comment: Problem is that I have string with \n characters. It is like https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/28 and then it will match all pattern. I'm not sure if \n character act same like newLine character.

Comment: This one is ok. Thank you :]

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '#buffer is with your sample data
/\(\n\)\{0,1\}\([[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]*\)$/ s//Last New line: \1 Last -line \2/'
```

- posix version
- allow a string with 1 line only (agree not your sample)
- allow to be with or without the last new line